# JavaScript line added to HTML script bracket make error 500

Tags: javascript, html

i have an issue with a webpage that produce error 500 after adding the following line :

```
discordInvite.init({inviteCode: 'sK5R76jTmu'});
```

inside the script bracket :

```
<script src="./discordInvite.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
discordInvite.init({inviteCode: 'sK5R76jTmu'});
discordInvite.render();
</script>
```

The page work fine without that line only and, if i juste type the commande in consol (chrome consol), the page render the results (typing the script in the order init + render).

For more details about the JS script, here is a link to the original git page :
https://github.com/Aegis7Gaming/Discord-Invite-JS-HTML-CSS

and here is the page i'm trying to implement this on  :
http://www.ats.rf.gd/ (part of the script is in the end of the body)

thanks in advance for your help i can't understand the logic behind it.

Comment: 500 errors are server side errors. Have you checked your server's logs?

Comment: Thanks it helped so much

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by replacing

```
discordInvite.init({inviteCode: 'sK5R76jTmu'});
```

by

```
discordInvite.init({inviteCode: "sK5R76jTmu"});
```